# Как выделить текст между маркерами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

```
import re

def between_markers(text: str, begin: str, end: str) -> str:
    """
       returns substring between two given markers
    """
    if begin in text or end in text:
        x=re.compile((begin if begin in text else r'')+r'(?P<word>.+)'+(end if end in text else r''))
        y=x.search(text)
    else:
        return text
    return y.group('word')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Example:')
    print(between_markers('What is >apple<', '>', '<'))
    print(between_markers("<head><title>My new site</title></head>",
                       "<title>", "</title>"))
    print(between_markers('No[/b] hi', '[b]', '[/b]'))
    print(between_markers('No [b]hi', '[b]', '[/b]'))
```

Я хочу сделать с помощью 're', но на последних двух строках кода он считает и маркеры.

Можно ли это исправить?

Результат должен быть такой:

```
assert between_markers('What is >apple<', '>', '<') == "apple", "One sym"
assert between_markers("<head><title>My new site</title></head>",
                       "<title>", "</title>") == "My new site", "HTML"
assert between_markers('No[/b] hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'No', 'No opened'
assert between_markers('No [b]hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'hi', 'No close'
```

Comment: Исправьте отступы кода в вопросе. Добавьте пример данных и ожидаемый результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
def between_markers(text: str, begin: str, end: str) -> str:
    """
    returns substring between two given markers
    """
    begin = re.escape(begin) if begin in text else ""
    end = re.escape(end) if end in text else ""
    pat = re.compile(fr".*?{begin}(.+){end}.*")
    return pat.sub(r"\1", text)
```

тесты:

```
In [27]: between_markers('What is >apple<', '>', '<')
Out[27]: 'apple'

In [28]: between_markers("<head><title>My new site</title></head>", "<title>", "</title>")
Out[28]: 'My new site'

In [29]: between_markers('No[/b] hi', '[b]', '[/b]')
Out[29]: 'No'

In [30]: between_markers('No [b]hi', '[b]', '[/b]')
Out[30]: 'hi'
```

- [Описание `f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
- [Описание `r-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

Comment: работает отлично Thanks, а что значить fr. r - raw, f?

Comment: "f" и "r" - модификаторы строк отвечающие соответственно за интреполяцию строк (`f-strings`) и за сырые строки (`raw strings`)